# Collections.emptyList() vs. new instance

Tags: java, collections, empty-list

In practice, is it better to return an empty list like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29):

```
return Collections.emptyList();
```

Or like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29):

```
return new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

Or is this completely dependent upon what you're going to do with the returned list?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

The main difference is that [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) returns an *immutable* list, i.e., a list to which you cannot add elements. (Same applies to the [`List.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--) introduced in Java 9.)

In the rare cases where you *do* want to modify the returned list, `Collections.emptyList()` and `List.of()` are thus **not** a good choices.

I'd say that returning an immutable list is perfectly fine (and even the preferred way) as long as the contract (documentation) does not explicitly state differently.

---

In addition, `emptyList()` [might not create a new object with each call.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--)

> Implementations of this method need not create a separate List object for each call. Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)

The implementation of `emptyList` looks as follows:

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

So if your method (which returns an empty list) is called very often, this approach may even give you slightly better performance both CPU and memory wise.

Comment: So, would `Collections.emptyList()` be more suitable for let's say, error checking and the like?

Comment: API clients won't get `NullPointerException` by returning `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `null`.

Comment: @PK_J makes an important point.  `Collections.emptyList()` is iterable and returns a length, so it can be used in for loops without an exception being thrown.

Comment: what about using `List.of()`?

Comment: @MrCholo, same as with `emptyList()`. Answer updated.

Comment: @aioobe so why would a List<Item> for a cached RecyclerView list in the Adapter class use Collections.emptyList() if the list will be added to and modified:

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordListAdapter.java

Comment: @AJW, nothing is added to that list. The list is replaced by another list here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordListAdapter.java#L61

Comment: @aioobe so it is good to use a Collections.emptyList in this case because it will only have a single instance?

Comment: @AJW, yes. But compared to, say, `new ArrayList<>()` it also makes the design decision clear; elements will not be added to this list.

Comment: the difference between _emptyList()_ and _EMPTY_LIST_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870819/what-is-the-difference-between-collections-emptylist-and-collections-empty-lis?rq=1

Answer (score 58):

Starting with Java 5.0 you can specify the type of element in the container:

```
Collections.<Foo>emptyList()
```

I concur with the other responses that for cases where you want to return an empty list that stays empty, you should use this approach.

Comment: Starting with Java 7, you can let the compiler infer the type parameter of the generic method invocation from the target type: `List<Foo> list = Collections.emptyList()`

Answer (score 33):

`Collections.emptyList` is immutable so there is a difference between the two versions so you have to consider users of the returned value.

Returning `new ArrayList<Foo>` always creates a new instance of the object so it has a very slight extra cost associated with it which may give you a reason to use `Collections.emptyList`.  I like using `emptyList` just because it's more readable.

Answer (score 19):

Be carefully though. If you return `Collections.emptyList()` and then try to do some changes with it like `add()` or smth like that, u will have an `UnsupportedOperationException()` because `Collections.emptyList()` returns an immutable object.

Answer (score 9):

I would go with `Collections.emptyList()` if the returned list is not being modified in any way (as the list is immutable), otherwise I would go with option 2.

The benefit of `Collections.emptyList()` is that the same static instance is returned each time and so there is not instance creation occurring for each call.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Collections.emptyList()` if you want to make sure that the returned list is never modified.

This is what is returned on calling `emptyList()`:

```
/**
 * The empty list (immutable). 
 */
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList();
```

Comment: I arrived here trying to find out if calling `Collections.emptyList()` had a construction cost. Seeing the implementation details (though probably not the same on all JVMs) confirm that it doesn't. @Atul, which JVM is this from?

Answer (score 3):

The given answers stress the fact that `emptyList()` returns an immutable `List` but do not give alternatives. The Constructor `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` special cases `0` so returning `new ArrayList<>(0)` instead of `new ArrayList<>()` might also be a viable solution:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

[...]

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
 *
 * @param  initialCapacity  the initial capacity of the list
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the specified initial capacity
 *         is negative
 */
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

(sources from Java 1.8.0_72)

Comment: I disagree with your approach. You save a bit of memory and CPU on the initialization, but if the list you returned is ever modified, you lose that time when the list reallocates a new array. If a lot of elements are added to the list over time, this could pile up into more of a performance bottleneck due to [the much slower growth rate](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29). I much prefer sticking to the convention of an unmodifiable empty list or a usable, modifiable list.

Comment: As I tried to stress with my wording (_might be viable_): it all depends on your use case. I would generally _either_ return mutable _or_ unmutable Collections, not a mixture depending on wether they are empty or not. And to counter the "much slower claim": [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal%28int%29) is the current implementation.

Comment: Oh man, look at me citing JDK 2 major versions out of date. So java8 avoids the bottleneck entirely by jumping up to the default capacity from an initial size of 0. Sorry I was so wrong.