# What is the use of Collections.EMPTY_MAP, EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_SET

Tags: java

Since all of them are immutable, why would one want it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it's a better alternative to returning `null`.

```
public List<?> getList(){
    if(list == null){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return list;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552258/collections-emptylist-vs-new-instance)

Answer (score 1):

They are convenience features: for functions that must return a non-null value, you can use them and you don't have to create a new object and you can do equality checks on them.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the above:

** You gain some performance benefits when using a empty list/map/set in cases where a method caller would receive EMPTY_something instead of a instantiated List/Map. If you look into the source of Collections.java you can see the EmptyList, EmptyMap static classes with stripped down methods implementations unlike a regular ArrayList. HashMap.

** Save on JVM heap space as there is no initial capacity set for these empty collections.

The above may not look really significant, nevertheless important considerations and for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Returning an immutable list is fine; also its even the preferred way, as long as the documentation does not state differently.