# Android put List of List into parcel

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, parcelable

I have a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, how to do put it into a parcel? I would prefer not using serializing (but it will still be accepted if there is no other easier/better method).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hello = null;

dest.writeList(hello);

in.readList(hello,null);
```

Comment: I assume by "put in a parcel" you mean save it since you mentioned Serializing. if that's the case, and you really don't want to serialize (for some reason), then just write your own implementation to store/read the object to some file.

Comment: re @Kon: I just want to pass it between fragments/activities in android.

Comment: "parcel" is this something related to android. is android similar to java.  just curious but if its similar to java then its impl wud be similar :)

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042272/how-to-properly-implement-parcelable-with-an-arraylistparcelable