# Android pass list via bundle in onSavedInstance method

Tags: java, android

I need to save a list when the orientation changes. To do this I want to pass the data in through the `onSavedInstanceState` method but, I don't no how to go about doing this, please see example code below:

```
private List<EarSrt> leftAnswerList;
private List<EarSrt> rightAnswerList;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putCharSequenceArrayList("left_ear", leftAnswerList);
    outState.putCharSequenceArrayList("right_ear", rightAnswerList);
}
```

This code doesn't work as I'm passing in a custom list.

error: `The method putCharSequenceArrayList(String, ArrayList<CharSequence>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<EarSrt>)`

How can I pass this data into the bundle?  Do I use a `Parcelable`? If so, how would I go about using a `Parcelable` in the `onSavedStateChanged` method?

Also How to I retrieve the data do I use the `onRestoreInstanceState` method? If so, How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

So I've just realised that I can pass it in through the below code:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("left_ear", (Parcelable) leftAnswerList);
    outState.putParcelable("right_ear", (Parcelable) rightAnswerList);

}
```

Do I need to use the `onRestoreInstanceState` method or can I just say in the `onCreate` method `if(savedInstanceState != null)` then do something?

**Edit:**

onCreate Method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.hearing_test);

    ActivityHelper activityHelper = new ActivityHelper(this);

    activityHelper.setTitleTextSize(R.string.Hearing_Test, true);
    isPhone = activityHelper.isPhone();

    if(isPhone){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    View infoView  = (View)findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    infoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    notUnderstoodButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.not_understood_button);
    repeatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.repeat_button);
    progressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTextView);

    progressTextView.setText("Left ear: Step 1 of 9");

    notUnderstoodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            soundButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });

    repeatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            noisePlayer.seekTo(0);
            testPlayer.seekTo(0);

            noisePlayer.start();
            testPlayer.start();

            disableButtons();
        }
    });

    panLeft = false;
        initialiseArrays();
    getNextTest(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass your data via a `Bundle`, it need to implement the `Parceable` interface. In your case it means that `EarSrt` has to be a `Parceable` because you are using a `List` of it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1965084) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042753/1965084) how to implement a `Parceable`.

To restore your data, it doesn't matter, if `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate` is used. Quote from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my list already implements `parcelable` so it is just a case of getting the information back after the orientation has changed. The way I've done this is using `savedInstanceState.getParcelable("left_ear");` in the `onCreate` method. Thanks for the input really appreciate it.

Comment: I have however just debugged through it and it doesn't hit my breakpoints when I change the orientation and it doesn't seem to restart the activity, why is this?

Comment: Do you have android:configChanges in your activity xml file preventing the UI to recreate after rotation? If thaths not the reason please post your onCreate() code above

Comment: So I was being stupid, I do have `android:configChanges` on my activity xml, can I just leave it like this instead of saving the instanceState?

Comment: You can leave e.g. `android:configChanges="orientation"`,  but  it might have some disadvantages like uncorrect recreation on orientation change, because the `Activity` is not fully recreated. It really depends on your usage, it might be a solution for you. Have a look at this post to clarify when to use `android:configChanges` or when not to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/1965084

Comment: Thanks for the info, so I suppose I should do it using `savedInstanceState` because if something interrupts the app, then it will restart the activity. I Implemented it and I get a cast class error when I go to another activity Ill reproduce and show you the error I get

Comment: I've ended up keeping `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest file and overidding the `onCOnfigurationChange` method to update the activity with the correct data. Thanks for your help @alex, helped me get to the bottom of the issue