# how to properly implement Parcelable with an ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, parcelable

I have an `ArrayList` from my class. I'm trying to pass it through `Parcelable`, but get an error.
Below is the structure of the class and the code itself. How can I pass this type of data?

Class

```
class Lists{
    String name_opt;
    byte[] value;
}

class ConfigStruct{
    String page;
    String name;
    String type;
    byte[] val_size;
    byte[] max_lenght;
    byte[] min_lenght;
    byte[] value;
    List<Lists> list;
    View view;
}
```

ConfigStructParcelable

```
public class ConfigStructParcelable implements Parcelable {

    List<Tabs.ConfigStruct> structs;

    public ConfigStructParcelable(ArrayList<Tabs.ConfigStruct> data){
        this.structs = data;
    }
    public ConfigStructParcelable(Parcel in){

        this.structs = in.readArrayList(null);//?
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(structs); //?
    }

    public static Creator<ConfigStructParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<ConfigStructParcelable>() {
        @Override
        public ConfigStructParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ConfigStructParcelable(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ConfigStructParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ConfigStructParcelable[size];
        }
    };

}
```

I have marked two spots "//?" to understand how to properly write to the parcel and how to reconstruct it.

Post by link didn't help.

[how to properly implement Parcelable with an ArrayList<Parcelable>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042272/how-to-properly-implement-parcelable-with-an-arraylistparcelable/7042757)

Comment: both ConfigStruct and Lists classes should also implement parcelable

Comment: Why not just use a library? http://parceler.org

Comment: How implement this classes to parcelable. I don't understend