# How to make a class with nested objects Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I'd like to make class A Parcelable.

```
public class A {
    public String str;
    public ArrayList<B> list;
}
```

This is what I've come up with so far. However it crashes with a NullPointerException. The problem are these two statements: `dest.writeList(list);` & `in.readList(list, this.getClass().getClassLoader());`.
I can't figure out what to do from here :(

**Class A**

```
public class A implements Parcelable {
    public String str;
    public ArrayList<B> list;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
        dest.writeList(list);
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
        in.readList(list, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<A>() {
        public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new A(in);
        }

        public A[] newArray(int size) {
            return new A[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B implements Parcelable {
    public String str;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
    }

    private B(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<B>() {
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new B(in);
        }

        public B[] newArray(int size) {
            return new B[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I finally figured out what to type into Google :), and found this [Android, How to use readTypedList method correctly in a Parcelable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774645/android-how-to-use-readtypedlist-method-correctly-in-a-parcelable-class)

The solution was to use `read-/writeTypedList` instead. I also initialize the arraylist to avoid any further NullPointerException.

**Class A**

```
public class A implements Parcelable {
    public String str;
    public ArrayList<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
        dest.writeTypedList(list);
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
        in.readTypedList(list, B.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<A>() {
        public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new A(in);
        }

        public A[] newArray(int size) {
            return new A[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B implements Parcelable {
    public String str;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
    }

    private B(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<B>() {
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new B(in);
        }

        public B[] newArray(int size) {
            return new B[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, it wouldn't let me and then I sort of forgot about it :)

Comment: @Snæbjørn +1 for showing how to make a parcelable class that contain non-primitive or custom types.

Comment: Awesome example. May I suggest you fix the names of the "AcreateFromParcel" functions in both classes? In the A class should be "public A createFromParcel" (missing space) and in the B class should be "public B createFromParcel". Yeah, it's trivial but for newbies can be troublesome.

Answer (score 32):

If you have **only one `Parcelable` object** inside your main `Parcelable` object, not list like the accepted answer case. Then it will be like the following:

**Class A**

```
public class A implements Parcelable {
    public String str;
    public B objectB;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //The parcelable object has to be the first one
        dest.writeParcelable(objectB, flags);
        dest.writeString(str);
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        this.objectB = in.readParcelable(B.class.getClassLoader());
        str = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<A>() {
        public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new A(in);
        }

        public A[] newArray(int size) {
            return new A[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B implements Parcelable {
    public String str;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(str);
    }

    private B(Parcel in) {
        str = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<B>() {
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new B(in);
        }

        public B[] newArray(int size) {
            return new B[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** 
Please note that the order that you write and read the `Parcelable` object matters. Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764742/1364896) for more details

Answer (score 3):

At Write to parcel

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name); //if String
    parcel.writeTypedList(assignedEmployees); //if List with custom class, eg. List<AssignedEmployee> assignedEmployees
    parcel.writeParcelable(checkin,i); //if custom class, eg. Checkin checkin;
    }
```

At Constructor for reading it back

```
 protected A(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        assignedEmployees = in.createTypedArrayList(AssignedEmployee.CREATOR);
        checkin = in.readParcelable(Checkin.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

where AssignedEmployee, Checkin where custom classes and it should implement Parcelable.

Answer (score 2):

Just press ALT+ENTER and replace Parcelable it will implement all the necessary implementation

Comment: Try this answer It does all the works automatically You don't have to write a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here's a [generic version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908946/6241054)

```
class Item<T : Parcelable> (val model: T, val index: Int ) : Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) :
        this(parcel.readParcelable(
          Item<T>::model.javaClass.classLoader),
          parcel.readInt()
        ) {}

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel?, flag: Int) {
        parcel?.writeParcelable(model, 0)
        parcel?.writeInt(index)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Item<Parcelable>> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Item<Parcelable> {
            return Item(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Item<Parcelable>?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Parcelable code generator plugin from prefs, from there you can create the parcelable boiler plate code by doing:
- right click class name within model
- select generate
- select Parcelable

presto - your model will be updated with necessary Parcelable boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

I was unfortunately using a class (`BarEntry`) from a 3rd party library which was not able to be parceled. I solved my problem by passing through `Intent` an array of `float`s and then reconstructing my `BarEntry` objects at the receiving end.

This is sub-optimal but it can be a useful process if anyone has a similar circumstance where creating a parcel able object is not an option.