# How to make nested ArrayLists parcelable

Tags: android

To pass an arrayList of objects to a fragment, I have to make the list objects parcelable.

```
public mObjectClass implements Parcelable {

    // Some code

}
```

The problem is that one of the attributes in my list objects is another object-based arrayList.

```
public mObjectClass implements Parcelable {

        // Some code

        private ArrayList<someOtherObject> anotherArrayList;

    }
```

How can I make mObjectClass parcelable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446359/android-class-parcelable-with-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someOtherObject` has to implement `Parcelable` (not extend has in your question) too. Then you can call `parcel.writeTypedList(anotherArrayList);` to write it and `parcel.readTypedList(yourList, someOtherObject.CREATOR)` to read it back. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E))

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178736/how-to-make-a-class-with-nested-objects-parcelable) the same question as mine?

Comment: Thanks. Let me figure it out, and I will check mark you when I fully understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is heavily influenced by some Stackoverflow posts, including
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178998/2694254).

Essentially make both Classes parcelable and make use of someOtherClasses Parcelable.Creator.

mObjectClass:

```
public class mObjectClass implements Parcelable {

    private ArrayList<someOtherObject> anotherArrayList;

    //add getter + setter...

    public mObjectClass() {
        anotherArrayList = new ArrayList<someOtherObject>();
    }

    public mObjectClass(Parcel in) {

        anotherArrayList = new ArrayList<someOtherObject>();
        in.readTypedList(anotherArrayList, someOtherObject.CREATOR);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel outParcel, int flags) {

        outParcel.writeTypedList(anotherArrayList);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

        @Override
        public mObjectClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new mObjectClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public mObjectClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new mObjectClass[size];
        }
    };
}
```

someOtherObject:

```
public class someOtherObject implements Parcelable {
    String someString;

    //add getter + setter...

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

        out.writeString(someString);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<someOtherObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<someOtherObject>() {
        public someOtherObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new someOtherObject(in);
        }

        public someOtherObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new someOtherObject[size];
        }
    };

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public someOtherObject(Parcel in) {
        someString = in.readString();

    }

    public someOtherObject() {
    }

    public someOtherObject(String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
}
```

Tada, you are now able to add mObjectClass as extra to your intents after initialising it and using a setter to set the Arraylist with other someOtherObjects.