# How to send class object through intent by implement parcable. Unable to marshal value error

Tags: android, object, android-intent, parcelable

I've one class, in which array list is there. How to send it through intent. following i did for my class

```
public class MakeOrder implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("refno")
@Expose
private String refno;
@SerializedName("ddesc")
@Expose
private String ddesc;
@SerializedName("free")
@Expose
private String free;
@SerializedName("fgift")
@Expose
private String fgift;
@SerializedName("sgift")
@Expose
private String sgift;
@SerializedName("sandage")
@Expose
private SandageResponse sandage;
@SerializedName("inst")
@Expose
private String inst;
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
@SerializedName("discount")
@Expose
private String discount;
@SerializedName("coupon")
@Expose
private Coupon coupon;
@SerializedName("delivery")
@Expose
private String delivery;
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;
@SerializedName("otype")
@Expose
private String otype;
@SerializedName("ptype")
@Expose
private String ptype;
@SerializedName("app_id")
@Expose
private String appId;
@SerializedName("app_key")
@Expose
private String appKey;
@SerializedName("request")
@Expose
private String request;
@SerializedName("tablename")
@Expose
private String tablename;
@SerializedName("staff")
@Expose
private String staff;

public String getTablename() {
    return tablename;
}

public void setTablename(String tablename) {
    this.tablename = tablename;
}

public String getStaff() {
    return staff;
}

public void setStaff(String staff) {
    this.staff = staff;
}

public String getRefno() {
    return refno;
}

public void setRefno(String refno) {
    this.refno = refno;
}

public String getDdesc() {
    return ddesc;
}

public void setDdesc(String ddesc) {
    this.ddesc = ddesc;
}

public String getFree() {
    return free;
}

public void setFree(String free) {
    this.free = free;
}

public String getFgift() {
    return fgift;
}

public void setFgift(String fgift) {
    this.fgift = fgift;
}

public String getSgift() {
    return sgift;
}

public void setSgift(String sgift) {
    this.sgift = sgift;
}

public SandageResponse getSandage() {
    return sandage;
}

public void setSandage(SandageResponse sandage) {
    this.sandage = sandage;
}

public String getInst() {
    return inst;
}

public void setInst(String inst) {
    this.inst = inst;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public String getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}

public Coupon getCoupon() {
    return coupon;
}

public void setCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
    this.coupon = coupon;
}

public String getDelivery() {
    return delivery;
}

public void setDelivery(String delivery) {
    this.delivery = delivery;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getOtype() {
    return otype;
}

public void setOtype(String otype) {
    this.otype = otype;
}

public String getPtype() {
    return ptype;
}

public void setPtype(String ptype) {
    this.ptype = ptype;
}

public String getAppId() {
    return appId;
}

public void setAppId(String appId) {
    this.appId = appId;
}

public String getAppKey() {
    return appKey;
}

public void setAppKey(String appKey) {
    this.appKey = appKey;
}

public String getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setRequest(String request) {
    this.request = request;
}




@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.refno);
    dest.writeString(this.ddesc);
    dest.writeString(this.free);
    dest.writeString(this.fgift);
    dest.writeString(this.sgift);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.sandage, flags);
    dest.writeString(this.inst);
    dest.writeTypedList(this.items);
    dest.writeString(this.discount);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.coupon, flags);
    dest.writeString(this.delivery);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.user, flags);
    dest.writeString(this.otype);
    dest.writeString(this.ptype);
    dest.writeString(this.appId);
    dest.writeString(this.appKey);
    dest.writeString(this.request);
    dest.writeString(this.tablename);
    dest.writeString(this.staff);
}

public MakeOrder() {
}

protected MakeOrder(Parcel in) {
    this.refno = in.readString();
    this.ddesc = in.readString();
    this.free = in.readString();
    this.fgift = in.readString();
    this.sgift = in.readString();
    this.sandage = in.readParcelable(SandageResponse.class.getClassLoader());
    this.inst = in.readString();
    this.items = in.createTypedArrayList(Item.CREATOR);
    this.discount = in.readString();
    this.coupon = in.readParcelable(Coupon.class.getClassLoader());
    this.delivery = in.readString();
    this.user = in.readParcelable(User.class.getClassLoader());
    this.otype = in.readString();
    this.ptype = in.readString();
    this.appId = in.readString();
    this.appKey = in.readString();
    this.request = in.readString();
    this.tablename = in.readString();
    this.staff = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MakeOrder> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MakeOrder>() {
    @Override
    public MakeOrder createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new MakeOrder(source);
    }

    @Override
    public MakeOrder[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MakeOrder[size];
    }
};
}
```

**Please take a look of updated one**
I'm getting error like **unable to marshal value**
I made all class Parcelable. how to send its object through **Intent**
**Thanks in Advance**

**Logcat is like**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value    Models.PlaceOrder.Sub@41e10f80
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
at Models.PlaceOrder.Item.writeToParcel(Item.java:90)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1017)
at Models.PlaceOrder.MakeOrder.writeToParcel(MakeOrder.java:246)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6866)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1897)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1418)
at android.app.Activity.internalStartActivityForResult(Activity.java:3427)
at android.app.Activity.access$200(Activity.java:660)
at android.app.Activity$2.onStartActivity(Activity.java:3417)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForBusiness(Activity.java:5441)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3413)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3367)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3644)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3612)
```

**Items.java** where getting Exception

```
public class Item implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("itemid")
@Expose
private String itemid;
@SerializedName("qty")
@Expose
private String qty;
@SerializedName("sub")
@Expose
private List<Sub> sub = new ArrayList<Sub>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The itemid
 */
public String getItemid() {
    return itemid;
}

/**
 *
 * @param itemid
 * The itemid
 */
public void setItemid(String itemid) {
    this.itemid = itemid;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The qty
 */
public String getQty() {
    return qty;
}

/**
 *
 * @param qty
 * The qty
 */
public void setQty(String qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The sub
 */
public List<Sub> getSub() {
    return sub;
}

/**
 *
 * @param sub
 * The sub
 */
public void setSub(List<Sub> sub) {
    this.sub = sub;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.itemid);
    dest.writeString(this.qty);
    dest.writeList(this.sub);
}

public Item() {
}

protected Item(Parcel in) {
    this.itemid = in.readString();
    this.qty = in.readString();
    this.sub = new ArrayList<Sub>();
    in.readList(this.sub, Sub.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public Item createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Item(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Item[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: can you post the complete logcat? and line of the error?

Comment: please check it now, I updated the question

Comment: Whats in line 90 of Item.java? There is he error.

Comment: Anyway, this is not how a question is sopossed to be asked. First you asked something, and after we resolved it, you have changed all the question instead of adding the new problem (the title, the code). Now the given answers make no sense..

Comment: Oops!!! yu are ryt. thats my mistake

Comment: that is a class where list is thr **dest.writeList(this.sub);**

Comment: Add the code please. You are trying to write a list that maybe is not a parcel object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123710/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-adalpari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **implement Parcelable also in the Item and Coupon objects**.

Then when you add and read the list in you MakeOrder class:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    ...
    // to write the Item list
    dest.writeList(items);
    // to write Coupon object
    dest.writeParcelable(coupon, falgs);
}
```

BTW, your constructor is empty

```
private MakeOrder(Parcel in) {
    ...
    // to read the Item list
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    in.readList(items, Item.CREATOR);
    // to read Coupon object
    in.readParcelable(Coupon.CREATOR);
}
```

This link could help you:

> [How to make a class with nested objects Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178736/how-to-make-a-class-with-nested-objects-parcelable)

And this is the Parcelable documentation:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

**EDIT:**

The where more Percel problem added to the question.

Final solution in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123710/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-adalpari

Comment: its empty because i cant able to find the way to parcel List<Items> value

Comment: Ok, try this solution and tell me if it helps to you.

Comment: what abt other object like **Coupon** how to send it

Comment: for that i need to make coupon class also parcel. (Y) let me check all now.

Comment: I completed all but getting exception like **unable to marshal value**. whats the problem now?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to write into a Parcel an object that is not compatible. Maybe the list? you can try writeTypedList.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in extras like this:

```
Intent intent-new Intent(this,YouActvity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",yourModel);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity to retrive:

```
YouModel yourModel = (YourModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
  intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("value", orderList);
```

And in other Activity get it as:

```
  List<String> orderList=this.getIntent().
           getParcelableArrayListExtra("value");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: your answer is not about Parcelable, but about Serializable

Comment: Thanks for telling me the mistake , i have changed my answer

Comment: This way you are adding the list DIRECTLY, that is inside the object, into the intent. If you want to pass the entire object this is not well-structurated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `Parcelable` constructor is empty. If you leave it empty, then it won't work. You need to read fields from parcel the same order you wrote them in `writeToParcel()` method.

Then to write parcelable data to intent, `putExtra()` method of the intent. To extract data from intent, use `getParcelableExtra()` method of the intent

Comment: actually my question is how to pass the list item?