# Get generics class loader for parsing nested Parcelable generic field

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, parcelable

I have a wrapper of `Parcelable` generic type but `Parcel` constructing fails to compile because `T` class can not be determined generically

```
class MyItem<T : Parcelable> (val model: T) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : 
      this(parcel.readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader)) {

    }
}
```

Is there any solution to this case?

Comment: No idea if it's related, but why is your T declared `out` when you're passing it in for the constructor? Doesn't that mean it's not covariant and thus shouldn't be `out`? What happens if you remove `out`?

Comment: @PaulHicks true but it doesn't affect the issue

Comment: Yep didn't think so. Remember, T isn't a class, it's a formal parameter. You can use a [reified inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) for this sort of thing, but that won't work in a secondary constructor. You would have to use a normal reified inline function in a factory, or more likely, on a companion object.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why do you want such layout? For me it sounds like all potential callers will need to know type of `T` in advance... which makes the use of generics kind-of dubious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get the whole picture here is what I ended up with:

The use case is one has a `Parcelable` generic instance let's call it `model` which  should be completed with common properties of `Parcelable` wrapper in order to not pollute the model with extrinsic fields. For example `Item` wrapper.

In the example below the wrapper extra property gives us some type of `index`  :

```
class Item<T : Parcelable> (val model: T, val index: Int ) : Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) :
        this(parcel.readParcelable(
          Item<T>::model.javaClass.classLoader),
          parcel.readInt()
        ) {}

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel?, flag: Int) {
        parcel?.writeParcelable(model, 0)
        parcel?.writeInt(index)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Item<Parcelable>> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Item<Parcelable> {
            return Item(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Item<Parcelable>?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

So in the end we can have something like: `Item(Person("John"), 0)`, `Item(Person("Bill"), 1)`...

```
class PersonPagerFragment() : BasePagerFragment<Person>() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(itemList: ArrayList<Item<Person>>) 
          : PersonPagerFragment {

            val args = Bundle()
            val fragment = PersonPagerFragment()
            args.putParcelableArrayList("items", itemList)
            fragment.arguments = args

            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

extending class like:

```
class BasePagerFragment<T : Parcelable> : Fragment(){
    protected fun readBundle(bundle: Bundle?) {
        bundle.getParcelableArrayList<Item<T>>("items")    
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. You're not calling `createFromParcel` or `newArray` in any of the example code, how will those be used? The Builder pattern is often used to do this sort of thing, rather than a model / template object. Are external dependencies prevent you from using that this time?

Comment: @PaulHicks I'm not sure I follow your thought exactly but I think you mean that I don't use the static  methods? The provided methods in the example aswell as `CREATOR`  are minimum requirement to extend `Parcelable`. My guess is `putParcelableArrayList` and `getParcelableArrayList` or `putParcelable` and  `getParcelable` methods use these. Unfortunately the source isn't downloaded on the API I use :(

Comment: Ah, there's a specific well-known `Parcelable` API. I didn't know that. It's probably not important for this question though.

Comment: @PaulHicks somewhat it's a part of the Android API as alternative to `Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [reified inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) as a factory method to achieve this. I prefer to do this on a companion object. Here's an MCVE:

```
class MyItem<T> (val model: T) {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> from(parcel : T) : MyItem<T> {
            return MyItem<T>(T::class.java.newInstance())
        }
    }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mi = MyItem.from("hi")
    println("mi is a ${mi::class}")
}
```

Comment: Obviously a trivial case here since I don't have your `readParcelable` method. Hopefully it's easy to translate to your exact case.

Comment: The problem in my case is that I don't have instance of `T` .
The `constructor(parcel: Parcel)` is auto invoked :(

Comment: You'll need to change that, or else change the primary constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to have a Parcel-type constructor, you could change that to be the primary constructor, and figure out the type of the MyItem then.

```
class Parcel

class MyItem(val parcel: Parcel) {
    inline fun <reified T> model() : T {
         // You code would be calling
         // `parcel.readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader)`
        return T::class.java.newInstance() as T
    }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // You don't ned to know the out type when constructing MyItem.
    val mi = MyItem(Parcel())

    // But you do need to know it when calling model()
    val model : String = mi.model()

    println("mi.model is a ${model::class}")
}
```

Comment: When I replaced String with Parcel, I found some significant issues with my first answer here :) Try this second version.

Comment: 10x for your  assistance it was very helpful