# Parcelable list inside Parcelable class not reading back with Parcel.readTypedList

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable

I have two Activities, A and B. I am trying to send object from Activity A, to Activity B. When in Activity A, I can see that my List contains two items, but when I retrieve it in Activity B, the List contains 7000000+ records.

Here is my Assessment class, that implements `Parcelable`, and contains an `ArrayList<Photo>` which should be parcelable as well.

Assessment POJO:

```
public class Assessment extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {
    public Assessment(){

    }

    @SerializedName("Vehicle")
    private String vehicle;

    @SerializedName("Photos")
    private List<Photo> photos;

    @Bindable
    public String getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }
    public void setVehicle(String vehicle) {

        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.vehicle);
    }

    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }
    public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {

        this.photos = photos;
    }

    protected Assessment(Parcel in) {
        vehicle = in.readString();
        photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
        in.readTypedList(photos, Photo.CREATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(vehicle);
        dest.writeTypedList(photos);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Assessment> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Assessment>() {
        @Override
        public Assessment createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Assessment(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Assessment[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Assessment[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Photo POJO:

```
public class Photo implements Parcelable {

    public Photo(){

    }

    @SerializedName("PhotoPath")
    private String photoPath;
    public String getPhotoPath() {
        return photoPath;
    }
    public void setPhotoPath(String photoPath) {
        this.photoPath = photoPath;
    }

    @SerializedName("Base64PhotoString")
    private  String photoBase64String;
    public String getPhotoBase64String() {
        return photoBase64String;
    }
    public void setPhotoBase64String(String photoBase64String) {
        this.photoBase64String = photoBase64String;
    }

    protected Photo(Parcel in) {
        photoPath = in.readString();
        photoBase64String = in.readString();
    }

    //region parelable
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(photoPath);
        dest.writeString(photoBase64String);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Photo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Photo>() {
        @Override
        public Photo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Photo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Photo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Photo[size];
        }
    };
    //endregion
}
```

Here is how I send the object via `Intent` from Activity A, to Activity B:

```
public void OnAdapterItemClicked(View view){
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.andrewkp.gaassessing.DisplayAssessment.class);
        Assessment extraAssessment = getAssessmentFromCollection(view); //extraAssessment.getPhotos().size() == 2
        activityIntent.putExtra("assessment", extraAssessment); 
        startActivity(activityIntent);
    }
```

And here is how I read the `Parcelable` object in Activity B:

```
assessment = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("assessment");
```

I have looked at the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178736/how-to-make-a-class-with-nested-objects-parcelable), and I follow exactly what they do, but my photos list does not persist through to Activity B:

When I debug the readTypedList method in Parcel class, I can see that it adds 7000000+ records to my ArrayList, but never removes them.  Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: Do you get a `BINDER TRANSACTION FAILED` message? There is a 1mb shared Binder limit, trying to send images as base64 strings would easily reach that limit almost immediately (depending on image size of course). A `FileProvider` might be a better option for sharing images - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: This is valuable information. Thanks. I will have a look at FileProvider, as I am not sure what it is.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are able to put up to **1MB** of data in a `Bundle` encapsulated inside `Intent`.

You will get bunch of errors when sending `PhotoBase64String` in `Bundle`.

However, in order to overcome this issue, I would suggest *path/URI* of your photo to your second activity. Then in your second activity, read photo from that path, and perform your desired operation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. My photo objects, are retrieved from an external web api, so I will have to ignore/strip the base64 property from the model. Thanks

Comment: You can talk to web developer too. Its not a good idea to get whole Base64 string in api response. Apis has its limitation too. You can get bucket url of image instead of getting whole object.