# NullPointerException when trying to read parcel ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I've got a class Message that implements Parcelable. It partly contains an ArrayList, AttachmentsData is also one of my classes. When I'm trying to pass a Messageobject from my MainActivity to another activity I get NullPointerException when trying to read this ArrayList.
AttachmentsData also implements Parcelable.

The error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.incentive/com.example.incentive.Comments}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 1at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   android.os.Parcel.readTypedList(Parcel.java:1638)
>   com.example.incentive.messagemodel.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:88)
>   com.example.incentive.messagemodel.Message.(Message.java:40)
>   com.example.incentive.messagemodel.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:103)
>   com.example.incentive.messagemodel.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:1)
>   android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1992)
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1854)
>   android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2094)
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
>   android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1158)
>   com.example.incentive.Comments.onCreate(Comments.java:70)
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)

In "public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)" when I'm writing the ArrayList:

```
dest.writeTypedList(attachments);
```

And what seems to be causing the error, in "private void readFromParcel(Parcel in)":

```
in.readTypedList(attachments, AttachmentsData.CREATOR);
```

I've tried finding different ways of solving it and have tried some versions, one being:

```
in.readList(attachments, AttachmentsData.class.getClassLoader());
```

But the app crashes.. Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? Or rather, I'm obviously writing or reading the ArrayList in a way that's not correct, but what is the right way?

Thanks,
Kristina

**EDIT**
I may just have solved it,
I changed the in to

```
attachments = in.createTypedArrayList(AttachmentsData.CREATOR);
```

Seems to be working! I guess it may have the same effect as David Wasser's answer?

Comment: "attachments" is your ArrayList????

Comment: @Mzzl that isn't possible. If `in` were null, you wouldn't get an exception in `readTypedList()` because you would never get to that method. The NPE would be thrown in the method that called it.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Yes, attachments is my ArrayList. I probably should have written that, sorry.

Comment: I can try it but if you look under EDIT in my original post, that seems to be working as well. Or do you think that solution is something that will crash because of something else at a later point?

Comment: @Phoebe Your solution is also fine. No worries.

Comment: this is the solution that worked for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774645/android-how-to-use-readtypedlist-method-correctly-in-a-parcelable-class

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the `attachments` variable to a list before you call `readTypedList()`, like this:

```
attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentsData>();
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you have just declared your ***ArrayList< AttachmentsData>()*** globally. You have not initialized it.

So you have to initialize that before calling ***readTypedList()***

And Globally declared as a

```
ArrayList<AttachmentsData> attachments ;
```

Like:

```
attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentsData>();
```