# error in read from parcel in Android

Tags: android, parcelable

//    While reading from parcel it is giving me error cannot convert void in array list.

```
Source Code:






 public class GetTripsByUserIdModel implements Parcelable{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private String success;
     private String tripId;
     private String tripRequestedBy;
     private String [] tripRequestedTo;
     private String tripAcceptedById;
     private String tripAcceptedByName;
     private String tripConductedBy;
     private String tripStatus;
     private String tripCreatedOn;
     private String tripScheduledBeginOn;
     private String tripScheduledEndOn;
     private String tripStartOn;
     private String tripCompleteOn;
     private String tripNotes;
     private ArrayList<TripDetailModel> tripDetails;

     private boolean mIsSeparator;


     public GetTripsByUserIdModel() {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

     public GetTripsByUserIdModel(String tripId, String tripRequestedBy,String tripAcceptedById,String tripAcceptedByName,String tripConductedBy
       ,String tripStatus,String tripCreatedOn,String tripScheduledBeginOn,String tripScheduledEndOn,
       String tripStartOn,String tripCompleteOn,String tripNotes,ArrayList<TripDetailModel> tripDetails,boolean mIsSeparator){

       this.tripId = tripId;
       this.tripRequestedBy = tripRequestedBy;
       this.tripAcceptedById = tripAcceptedById;
       this.tripAcceptedByName = tripAcceptedByName;
       this.tripConductedBy = tripConductedBy;
       this.tripStatus = tripStatus;
       this.tripCreatedOn = tripCreatedOn;
       this.tripScheduledBeginOn = tripScheduledBeginOn;
       this.tripScheduledEndOn = tripScheduledEndOn;
       this.tripStartOn = tripStartOn;
       this.tripCompleteOn = tripCompleteOn;
       this.tripNotes = tripNotes;
       this.tripDetails = tripDetails;
       this.mIsSeparator = mIsSeparator;

     }


     public GetTripsByUserIdModel(Parcel in) {
      readFromParcel(in);
     }



     private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

           this.success = in.readString();
           this.tripId = in.readString();
           this.tripRequestedBy = in.readString();
           //this.tripRequestedTo = in.readStringArray(tripRequestedTo);
           this.tripAcceptedById = in.readString();
           this.tripAcceptedByName = in.readString();
           this.tripConductedBy = in.readString();
           this.tripStatus = in.readString();
           this.tripCreatedOn = in.readString();
           this.tripScheduledBeginOn = in.readString();
           this.tripScheduledEndOn = in.readString();
           this.tripStartOn = in.readString();
           this.tripCompleteOn = in.readString();
           this.tripNotes = in.readString();
           this.tripDetails = new ArrayList<TripDetailModel>(); 
           this.tripDetails = in.readTypedList(this.tripDetails, TripDetailModel.CREATOR);


        }

    }
```

//  While reading "in.readTypedList" on last line. It is giving error can not convert void into ArrayList().

```
//Please suggest any mistake i am doing.
```

PLEASE RESOLVE

Comment: in.readTypedList you are passing  this.tripDetails as parameter so why are you assigning the return value of the in.readTypedList to this.tripDetails again.Try removing the assignment  this.tripDetails = in.readTypedList(this.tr...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774645/android-how-to-use-readtypedlist-method-correctly-in-a-parcelable-class

Answer (score 1):

public final void readTypedList (List list, Creator c).
Return type of the readTypedList is void.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readTypedList(java.util.List, android.os.Parcelable.Creator)

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

           this.success = in.readString();
           this.tripId = in.readString();
           this.tripRequestedBy = in.readString();
           //this.tripRequestedTo = in.readStringArray(tripRequestedTo);
           this.tripAcceptedById = in.readString();
           this.tripAcceptedByName = in.readString();
           this.tripConductedBy = in.readString();
           this.tripStatus = in.readString();
           this.tripCreatedOn = in.readString();
           this.tripScheduledBeginOn = in.readString();
           this.tripScheduledEndOn = in.readString();
           this.tripStartOn = in.readString();
           this.tripCompleteOn = in.readString();
           this.tripNotes = in.readString();
           this.tripDetails = new ArrayList<TripDetailModel>(); 
           /*this.tripDetails = in.readTypedList(this.tripDetails, TripDetailModel.CREATOR);*/

           in.readTypedList(this.tripDetails, TripDetailModel.CREATOR);


        }
```