# When to return empty collections and when not too?

Tags: java, collections

This question regards to the function [public List inorderTraversal ()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39364/inorder-traversal-of-a-tree-without-recursion-or-stack).

Assume a case the root is null, the returned `List` is empty, ie size = 0. I am confused now since this is same as Collections.emptyList(). When should we use Collections.emptyList  ? Is this `inorderTraversal` right place to use it instead of list with size 0 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597277/why-would-someone-use-collections-emptylist-in-java

Comment: The rule of thumb is to not return null anywhere that an object is expected. Sooner or later somebody will use the code/method and **not** test for null... resulting in that all-time favourite NullPointerException.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. In the code you link to, `root` *can't* be `null` so a `List` with at least one element is always going to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List l = Collections.emptyList();
    l.clear();     // No NPE
    List p = null;
    p.clear();     // NPE
}
```

So, prefer returning emptyList rather than returning null..

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.emptyList` is a very useful means of storing a reference to an empty list (which I guess is kind of obvious).

The benefit of using it is that it's only going to occupy the memory required for a single list. Using it saves you the memory that you would use if you had multiple empty lists lying around. Also, as it's static, this List instance will always exist, whether you use it once, a thousand times or not at all.

You should use it when you wish to return a "static" list containing no objects. I use the term "static" here to indicate that the list is empty and will not be populated by any means. For example, if you have a data-access object and do a database-retrieval that yields no objects then your accessor should return a `Collections#emptyList`

However, if you have a list that is being used dynamically (and becomes empty as part of this), such as to back a data-structure like your own List implementation, then you should not use it as you need to keep a reference to the active list.

Additionally, if (as you should) you return defensive copies of internal arrays, then you will be able to use `Collections#emptyList` for when the internal list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would return an empty collection whenever it makes sense to do so.  If you need to distinguish between an empty collection and "uninitialised" or some `null` state, then you can return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of a resulting List just before `return`. If the size is 0, you can return `Collections.emptyList()`, so your empty `ArrayList` will become orphaned, and will be garbage collected.

Empty lists IMO a preferable to `null`, since they cat prevent `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Put simply: yes. This way, if `root` is `null` you can avoid creating `ArrayList` (and consuming memory unnecessarily) .

Although this is not what you ask about, but generally returning empty collection is preferred over returning `null` - it prevents many NPEs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `Collections.emptyList()` returns an *immutable* list, which means that adding to it, or removing from it will fail.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()