# Where exactly the java.util.Collections.emptyList() method is used in real application?

Tags: java, collections, empty-list

I am just curious to know where exactly the **java.util.Collections.emptyList()** method is used. Why such method is given which returns immutable list in Java? What could be done with it?

Comment: It's useful when your code would otherwise return `null`. Returning `null` is generally bad practice and you should seek to return a dummy object instead whenever possible (in this case, the empty list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would someone use Collections.emptyList in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597277/why-would-someone-use-collections-emptylist-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

It's useful when you want to return... an empty list. It's more efficient to reuse a canonical empty list than to create a new one each time.

```
List<Integer> numbersBetween(int from, int to) {
  if (to < from) return Collections.emptyList();
  else {
    //do what you have to do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In legacy applications it was quite common to use `null` values instead of empty lists, sets or maps.

```java
public List<String> getElements() {
  if (bla < 0) {
    return null;
  }
}

public List<String> getElements() {
  if (bla < 0) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

In my opinion, it is mostly better to work with empty `List<>`, `Set<>` or `Map<>` instead of `null` values.