# What is the difference between Collections.emptyList() and Collections.EMPTY_LIST

Tags: java, list, collections

In Java, we have [Collections.emptyList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) and [Collections.EMPTY_LIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST). Both have the same property:

> Returns the empty list (immutable). This list is serializable.

So what is the exact difference between using the one or the other?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

- `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` returns an old-style **`List`**
- `Collections.emptyList()` uses type-inference and therefore returns
  **`List<T>`**

**Collections.emptyList() was added in Java 1.5 and it is probably always preferable**. This way, you don't need to unnecessarily cast around within your code.

`Collections.emptyList()` intrinsically does the cast *for you*.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain of this, but I believe that using/returning the untyped version (EMPTY_LIST/EMPTY_SET/EMPTY_MAP) causes the compiler to give up on generics type checking within the given call chain. It essentially figures that it has wandered into old code lacking generic types and gives up.

Answer (score 20):

Lets get to the source :

```
 public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

They are absolutely equal objects.

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();

public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

The only one is that `emptyList()` returns generic `List<T>`, so you can assign this list to generic collection without any warnings.

Answer (score 14):

In other words, EMPTY_LIST is not type safe:

```
  List list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
  Set set = Collections.EMPTY_SET;
  Map map = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
```

As compared to:

```
    List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
    Set<Long> l = Collections.emptySet();
    Map<Date, String> d = Collections.emptyMap();
```