# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException(Can't add arraylist to list)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add `ArrayList` to `List`. `getSalesOrderitm()` is Salesorder item list.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(SalesOrder.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.ge("date", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(fdate)));
cr.add(Restrictions.le("date", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(tdate)));
List<SalesOrder> orderList = cr.list();
List<SalesOrderItem> itemList = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
double totalAmount = 0.00;
for (SalesOrder salesOrder : orderList) {
    itemList.addAll(salesOrder.getSalesorderyitm());
}
```

Below you can see hibernate mapping in Salesorder class

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=SalesOrderItem.class,mappedBy="salesorder",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public List<SalesOrderItem> getSalesorderyitm() {
    return salesorderyitm;
}
public void setSalesorderyitm(List<SalesOrderItem> salesorderyitm) {
    this.salesorderyitm = salesorderyitm;
}
```

Below you can see hibernate mapping in salesOrderItem class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SOI_SalesOrderId")
public SalesOrder getSalesorder() {
    return salesorder;
}
public void setSalesorder(SalesOrder salesorder) {
    this.salesorder = salesorder;
}
```

I got Below error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:342)
```

Comment: Why didn't you `new` your `itemList`?

Comment: @yassadi what is new?

Comment: Change this line `List<SalesOrderItem> itemList = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;` to 
`List<SalesOrderItem> itemList = new ArrayList< SalesOrderItem>();`

Comment: @yassadi Please post that, with a little more explanation, as an answer.  Please do not provide answers in comments.

Comment: @yassadi it's working, thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @yassadi already pointed out in one of the comments the problematic part of your code is this line:

```
List<SalesOrderItem> itemList = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

Simply change this line to

```
List<SalesOrderItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and you're done.

As stated in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST) `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` and `Collections.emptyList()` are/return **immutable** lists. That is you must not remove (ok, this is not really the problem with an empty list) or add elements to this list. These helper methods provided by the `Collections` class are more to be used as default return values where you want to avoid (memory) overhead by allocating new instances, if only the fact that the collection is empty is of interest.

The immutable characteristic is actually valid for a bunch of methods/members in the `Collections` class (`emptyList`, `singletonList`,`emptyMap`, `singletonMap`, ...). This always needs to be kept in mind, when using these helper methods.

When using the static members of `Collections`, such as `EMPTY_LIST`, `EMPTY_MAP`, etc. you might notice a compiler warning

> Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List

This is due to the missing type-inference for the static members. By using the corresponding methods such as `Collections.emptyList()` the correct generic types will be inferred automatically (`emptyList` simply casts to the wanted type) and you will get rid of this annoying warning without adding tons of boilerplate casts to your code. That is the helper methods should always be preferred over the members unless you want pre Java 1.5 compatibility, but these times are hopefully over by now.

See [What is the difference between Collections.emptyList() and Collections.EMPTY_LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870819/what-is-the-difference-between-collections-emptylist-and-collections-empty-lis)

Comment: You could add that one should prefer that method over the constant, when needing that empty thing.