# Empty list: What is the difference between Arrays.asList() and Collections.emptyList()?

Tags: java

If i need an empty list, I could use

```
Arrays.asList()
```

or

```
Collections.emptyList()
```

What is the difference between these two calls? Which one should I use?

Comment: Use the second one, the first one is there to create a list from the content of an array, it would be overkill to use this to create a new empty list.

Comment: `Collections.emptyList()` returns a immutable List, so if you need to add some items somewhere you should use a new  ArrayList instance `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: [You should check this post out :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552258/collections-emptylist-vs-new-instance)

Comment: Don't put the answer in your question, it is misleading, create your own answer to your own question instead

Comment: thanks @s0re for this link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Collections.emptyList()` is your best option because it reuses an object instead of creating a new object as it will be the case with `Arrays.asList()`.

**NB:** `Collections.emptyList()` returns an immutable object so if you intend to modify it later in your code you will need to create your list explicitly instead because you will face the same issue with `Arrays.asList()` as it is immutable too.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` is practically immutable as well: you can't add or remove anything, since the backing array can't be resized.

Comment: Additionally, it's not *necessarily* true that `Collections.emptyList()` will reuse an object. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()): "Implementations of this method **need not** create a separate List object for each call", the implication being that it *could*. However, it is likely that `Collections.emptyList()` won't involve creating more instances than `Arrays.asList()`, so I agree it is a better choice.

Comment: @AndyTurner you did not read my NB properly, I never said that Arrays.asList() is not immutable I simply said that Collections.emptyList() is immutable and if you want to modify you need to create a list instead

Comment: Read it again, and my comment remains. The two options have the same property of immutability, " so if you intend to modify it later in your code" you can't use `Arrays.asList()` either.

Comment: @AndyTurner indeed the javadoc says so but the code says something else: return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST

Comment: There is no "the" code. There are only some implementations which meet a specification, at least some of which return the same instance on each invocation. You shouldn't rely on the current implementation, if the documentation specifies that it can do something else.