# notifyDataSetChanged method on RecyclerView

Tags: android, node.js, android-recyclerview

I am tying to practice with RecyclerView by create simple app to sending and receiving tweet from nodejs server. In  main Activity I just list responses and in the second activity I send a simple tweet to server. I have a RecyclerView in my main Activity, it's job is showing received data as list. I do configure 
`RecyclerView` like below:

```
        //config recycler view
    mRyTweets = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ry_tweets);
    mRyTweets.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, new TweetAdapter.TweetEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onEditTweet(String tweetId, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteTweet(String tweetId, int position) {

        }
    });
    mRyTweets.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**and its layout:**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/default_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ry_tweets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/default_toolbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is where I receive response from a simple nodejs server:**

```
   private void getTweetsFromServer() {
    Call<List<TweetModel>> call = mTService.getTweets();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TweetModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TweetModel>> call, Response<List<TweetModel>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //update the adapter data
                mAdapter.updateAdapterData(response.body());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                ErrorModel errorModel = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Type is: " + errorModel.type + " , description "
                        + errorModel.description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

in this line `mAdapter.updateAdapterData(response.body());` I add response from server to my **adapter**:

```
public class TweetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TweetAdapter.TweetViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private List<TweetModel> mData = Collections.emptyList();
private TweetEventHandler mTweetEventHandler;

public TweetAdapter(Context context, TweetEventHandler tweetEventHandler) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mTweetEventHandler = tweetEventHandler;
}

public void updateAdapterData(List<TweetModel> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}
```

**in second activity i have a menu for sending tweet:**

```
           TweetModel tweetModel = new TweetModel();
        //assign tweet model values
        tweetModel.body = mETxTweetBody.getText().toString();
        tweetModel.feel = mSelectedMode;

        //create call generic class to send request to server
        Call<TweetModel> call = mTService.createNewTweet(tweetModel);
        //Async request
        //NOTE: you should always Async request since the sync request cause the crash of your app
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TweetModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TweetModel> call, Response<TweetModel> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
//
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully post tweet" + response.body().created_at
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();

                }
```

Everything is good, but when I send a new tweet in my main activity new tweet does not show immediately in my list and I have to do exit from app and run again. I don't know why `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` does not work?
what's  your suggestion ??

Comment: Question: Your new tweet going to the database in the server? Or does it add to the existing model? 
If you are adding it to the existing model, notify data set change will be suffice. However, if you are sending it to server, then you won't get it. Since the connection is not open.

Comment: @aa_oo  it just is saved in the simple json file.my server is local. and notify data set change does not work!!

Comment: sorry, I was busy wt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone.
I fixed my problem by

```
startActivityForResult(postNewTweetIntent,Constants.CREATE_OR_EDIT_TWEET_REQUEST_CODE);
```

in MainActivity and `setResult(RESULT_OK);` when I send tweet. and then in Activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.CREATE_OR_EDIT_TWEET_REQUEST_CODE &&
            resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        getTweetsFromServer();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

in this method`getTweetsFromServer();` I receive response from server and then I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for updating my list:

```
mAdapter.updateAdapterData(response.body());
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Collections.emptyList();` returns an immutable list. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552258/collections-emptylist-vs-new-instance).

Use:
 `List<Model> mData = new ArrayList<>();`

And then why don't you try this in you `update`:

```
public void updateAdapterData(List<TweetModel> data) {
  // instead of this  this.mData = data;
  this.mData.addAll(data);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And it should just work fine! Do reply if you need an explaination!

Comment: Yes, my bad, forgot that you use `Collections.emptyList();` which returns an immutable list. 

Use `mData = new ArrayList();` 

Ref: [Check this stack post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552258/collections-emptylist-vs-new-instance)

Comment: data it does not shows immediately in list again and i have to do restart my app.

Comment: with this solution too? (i.e no where the list is re-initialzed) right? only once? can you edit the update method in the post.

Comment: Yes this solution doesn't work.when I add a tweet the server responses data and on `onResponse` method by `updateAdapterData(response.body());` the list is re-initialized.

Comment: Yes then there lies your problem, the list should not be re-initialzed. it should be initialzed only once. Why dont you use the old way, pass the list to the adapter in its constructor. and then instead of using the `update` method just use the `list.addAll` method and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Comment: @this is main Activity compelet code [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/uai7azGr) and my [Adapter](http://pastebin.com/fsuJBiRj).where is my mistake?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137281/discussion-between-madscientist-and-sayres-kabir).