# What is the purpose of 'empty' Collection?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I found emptyEnumeration(), emptyIterator(), emptyList() and other methods in Collections class. I searched for examples and purpose but could not found an appropriate one.

It would be a great help if someone can explain with project usability example, wehre emptyList() needs to be created and it is also better to go with it than going with creating a `new ArrayList<>()` without adding any elements.

Comment: When you want to return an empty `List`?

Comment: [Collections.emptyList() vs. new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552258)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They actually return a casted, single instance, so you don't create new objects on the heap for each call to `emptyList()`. So it's faster and saves memory and GC.

It's an initializer that is used internally by `List`  implementations to decide whether they actually need to allocate space (even adding elements) or keep the list untouched if no elements will be added at runtime (because it happens sometimes, more often than you may think).

Those objects are *immutable* so you can safely reuse the same instance anywhere, without the synchronization you usually put in place to ensure object status integrity.

Comment: The important property of `Collections.emptyList()` etc that allows this usage is that they are immutable: there are no elements to remove, but you can't add any either. This means that a single instance can be safely reused, since there is no way one user can corrupt the instance for any other user.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the empty collection is to be an empty collection!  As remarked in a comment, there are times when it is appropriate for a method that returns a collection to be returning an empty collection.

As for why (e.g.) `Collections.emptyList()` is useful: well, why create your own empty list when you can reuse an existing empty list?  It's a minor convenience, a minor saving on memory.

If your code naturally arrives at a point where it (a) knows it needs to return an empty collection, and (b) does not have an empty collection that was created 'naturally', by which I mean something like having created the collection to hold results and then failed to find any such results, then the Collections facilities are handy.